# How to replace string character in Python?

Tags: python, str-replace

```
for i  in range(len(contents)):
    contents = contents.replace(contents[i],chr(ord(contents[i]) + 1)) 
print(contents)
for i in range(len(contents)):
    contents = contents.replace(contents[i],chr(ord(contents[i]) - 1))
print(contents)
```

This is where I get confused, shouldn't it just add 1 int to the character more and give you a character that is one byte (in UNICODE) above? Shouldn't it after you subtract one give you back the same result as before?

I have a string `This is some sample text!`. When I run the code, the string is converted to `Ukkz%kz%zqoh%zboqmh%zhzz%`.

Then, it should decrypt it back, but it show `Tees es sole salole sess`.

Comment: Try putting a print statement to show `contents` after each iteration of the loop and make it a simple string like `abc`... you'll find that in the first iteration you replace **all** `a`'s to `b`s making it `bbc`, then since the next one is `b`, you change **all** `b`s to `c`, so you get `ccc`, then in the last iteration, you change **all** `c`s to `d` so your final string is `ddd`... making all the `d`s go back a character will give you `ccc`...

Comment: Okay, so i am converting it to a list now to see if i can make it work that way. I will update you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jon Clements i have found a fix:

I converted the string into an array, then looped trough the array adding 1 to the character ordinal.

```
s = list(contents)

def encrypt(s):
    for i  in range(len(s)):
        s[i] = chr(ord(s[i]) + 1)
    ret = ''.join(s)
    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

```
contents = "This is some sample text!"
print(f"Original value of contents: {contents}")
for i  in range(len(contents)):
    contents = contents[:i]+contents[i:].replace(contents[i],chr(ord(contents[i]) + 1),1)
print(f"Modified value of contents: {contents}")
for i  in range(len(contents)):       
    contents = contents[:i]+contents[i:].replace(contents[i],chr(ord(contents[i]) - 1),1)
print(f"Reversed value of contents: {contents}")
```